# Threading on Winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am teaching myself how to operate with large numbers in complex loops.
In the main program, it will calling an method to perform some action.
In the example that I am working on it is just displaying the time in seconds.

As I am working the Form goes to Not Responding and crashes.
The screen looks like

[image: The Long Loop]

When the program is running, every second would be outputted to the screen letting the user see that the program is still running and not responding.

The code is as follows

```
private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    label1.Text = "Start";
    label2.Text = "Started";

    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 1;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Number";

    for (int index1 = 0; index1 < limit; index1++)
    {
        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < limit; index2++)
        {
            for (int index3 = 0; index3 < limit; index3++)
            {
                if ((stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds % 1000) == 0)
                {
                    timeCount++;
                    AddRowToDG();
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    label1.Text = "The count is " + count.ToString();
    // Stop.
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Double myTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    label2.Text = (myTime / 1000).ToString();
}

private void AddRowToDG()
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(timeCount.ToString());
}
```

If I use above 150 for the limit, the program goes to not responding.
In the programming that I will be actually using will be 10 to power of 12.

From the research that I have done, there is tasks and threads that can be used.
Which methodology should I use and where would I get the best resource to help me to make the choices in future?

Comment: So where is that thread that you *definitely* need to stop the UI from freezing??

Comment: You should operate your non-UI activities on a separate thread\task from the UI.  Your form is freezing because it's not being updated whilst your `BtnStart` code is running

Comment: Where's the "crash" information?

Comment: Start reading about [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# language have [`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task/) and [`System.Threading.Thread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread/) classes, but for Windows Forms you should use [`System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker/). There is [`DoWork`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork/) event to do your application logic in the different thread.

Comment: You can use Task in WinForms.  No issues.